# MySQL Server Gone away error While restoring the database in RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, rds, amazon-aurora

I am getting "**MySQL Server Gone away** error While restoring the large (2GB ) database in RDS.
I have checked many blogs and have changed the following parameters.

**Max_allowed_packets to 1GB
connect_timeout to 7200S.**

But still i am facing the same issue. And my RDS memory is touching the maximum level up-to 7GB. I have 8GB of RAM in my RDS with m4large MySQL RDS instance.
Please give me some solution for this issue.

Comment: is there a discspace problem ? also for tmpdir - SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VALUE LIKE '%tmp%';

Comment: We have 200GB HDD and the instance is new instance. SO the temp file may not be problem.

Comment: can you post how innodb_data_file_path is configured in the my.cnf. is it autoextend ?

Comment: Thank you for your response Bernd. I have intitated the MySQL in  RDS. Dont know where the innodb_file_path is configured in RDS instance.

Comment: ups - sorry - i didnt read this

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this ?

[rds-sql-server-gone-away](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-sql-server-gone-away/?nc1=h_ls)

and this:

[Changing MTU](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-drop-issues.html)

To set MTU on a Linux operating system

If your client runs in a Linux operating system, you can review and set the MTU value by using the ip command.

Run the following command to determine the current MTU value:

```
$ ip link show eth0
```

Review the value following mtu in the output.

If the value is not 1500, run the following command to set it:

```
$ sudo ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1500
```

I hope this can help.